# Is the Intel AppFramework compatible with Calabash-android?

Tags: calabash-android

Is AppFramework compatible with Calabash-android?
Personnally i tried hours and failed to access to html elements.

Comment: Can you post some code that you tried?

Comment: i deveopp my project based on this app: https://github.com/krisrak/appframework-templates#loginview-app. The code is here https://github.com/krisrak/appframework-templates/blob/master/template-LoginViewApp.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is compatible.
The diffulty  i had was not due to Intel AppFramework but to my ignorance of calabash under cordova.
There are good example, the main thing is to replace Webview by SystemWebView.